On Ramanujan's tau function
The Ramanujan tau function is given by
$$q\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)^{24}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tau(n)q^n\quad \ (|q|<1).$$
The values of $\tau(1),\tau(2),\ldots,\tau(10)$ are as follows:
$$1,\ -24,\ 252,\ -1472,\ 4830,\ -6048,\ -16744,\ 84480,\ -113643,\ -115920.$$
It is well known that the tau function is multiplicative. Thus, if $m$ and $n$ are positive integers with $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then
$$\tau(m)\tau(n)\tau(mn)=\tau(mn)^2$$
is a square. For example,
$$\tau(2)\tau(5)\tau(10)=\tau(10)^2=115920^2.$$
Recall that a perfect power has the the form $k^m$ with $k,m\in\{2,3,\ldots\}$.
Via Mathematica, I have verified that $|\tau(n)|$ is not a perfect power for every $n\le 10^6,$ and also there is no perfect power among $|\tau(m)\tau(n)|$ with $0<m<n\le 2000$. Based on this as well as heuristic arguments, I conjecture that the following question has a negative answer.
Question. Can $|\tau(m)\tau(n)|$ with $m\not=n$ be a perfect power?
Note that $\tau(1)\tau(n)=\tau(n)$ since $\tau(1)=1$.
For my other related postings, one may consult Questions
484763,
484846
and 484936.
Your comments are welcome!


“I conjecture that this question has a negative answer.”

Are you basing this on any heuristic arguments or just the fact that you haven’t found any by brute force?

Besides the two factors you mentioned, intuition is also vital for posing a conjecture. One may also ask why Lehmer conjectured that $\tau(n)$ is never zero.

@Zhi-WeiSun What is your intuition behind this conjecture?

What, if any, consequences might there be from some $|\tau(n)|$ being a perfect power?

@Zhi-WeiSun Regarding Lehmer's conjecture, there are conjectured asymptotic lower bounds on $|\tau(p)|$ for prime $p$ (by Serre, if I recall correctly, and based on theoretical basis).

@Zhi-WeiSun The vanishing of Ramanujan’s function, D. H. Lehmer It appears Lehmer’s interest stems from the fact that Tau function is generated from powers of Lacunary Series and it is of interest to investigate whether powers of lacunary series also have many zero coefficients.
