Questions on the reciprocals of the values of the tau function
Ramanujan's tau function is given by
$$q\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)^{24}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tau(n)q^n\quad \ (|q|<1).$$
This function plays an important role in the the theory of modular forms.
Lehmer's conjecture on the tau function states that $\tau(n)\not=0$
for any positive integer $n$.
Based on my belief that the tau function should have nice arithmetic properties, here I propose two conjectures involving the reciprocals of the values of the tau function.
Conjecture 1. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\tau(n)}$ converges absolutely. Moreover,
$$s=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\tau(n)}\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ t=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{|\tau(n)|}$$
are transcendental numbers with
$$s\approx 0.9616003152818447641035394
\ \ \text{and}\ \ t\approx 1.04678780296755839729371.$$
Question 1. Under Lehmer's conjecture, can one prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\tau(n)}$ converges absolutely?
Conjecture 2. All the finite sums
$$\sum_{i\in I}\frac1{\tau(i)}\ \ \ (I\subseteq\{1,2,3,\ldots\}\ \text{and}\ |I|<\infty)$$
are distinct. In particular,
$$\sum_{i\in I}\frac1{\tau(i)}\not=0$$
for any  $I\subseteq\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ with $0<|I|<\infty$.
Remark. Via Mathematica, I have verified that all the sums
$$\sum_{i\in I}\frac1{\tau(i)}\ \ (I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,20\})$$
are indeed pairwise different.
Question 2. Can one find any counterexamples to Conjecture 2?
Your comments are welcome!

Conjecture 2 implies that $|\tau(n)|\ (n=1,2,3,\ldots)$ are distinct. I have verified that $|\tau(n)|\ (n=1,\ldots,10^6)$ are indeed distinct.

Related questions by same user, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/484517/an-extension-of-lehmers-conjecture-on-ramanujans-tau-function and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/484381/on-ramanujans-tau-function

I guess that $|\tau(n)|>2n^4$ for any integer $n>2$. The inequality holds for every $n=3,4,\ldots,10^6$.

Via Mathematica, I have verified Conjecture 2 for $I \subseteq {1,2,...,25}$.

Do you have reason to expect a positive answer to Question 1?
